# accounts both of A and of B

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

> 1. He gives accounts both of A and **of** B.
> 2. He gives accounts both of A and B.

Are both 1 & 2 valid ? Is there any difference?

Comment: They are valid and equivalent; you can even say _He gave accounts of both A and B_.

Comment: @oerkelens Both gave and give are the same in this case?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I changed the tense. No, _gives_ is present simple - he's doing it now, whereas _gave_ is simple past - he did it in the past. The normal meaning of the different tenses applies :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases it would be more "natural" to say...

> *...accounts **of both** A and B*

...because ***both*** specifically applies to ***A and B***, so the nearer it's placed to them, the better. You would normally use the *"both of A and of B"* format where ***A*** is a relatively long text string, in which case you repeat ***of*** mainly to "remind" the reader of the earlier ***both*** which might otherwise be "forgotten"...

> 1: *Having heard the accounts **of both** Tom **and** Dick, I find them equally guilty of Harry's murder.*
>    2: *But taking account **both of** Tom's recent substantial donation to the Magistrates Benevolent fund, **and of** Dick's refusal to contribute, I rule that Tom be fined £2, and Dick be sentenced to death.*

But really these are just stylistic choices, and it would not be "wrong" to reverse the above usages.